# Change the displayed name of languages

Tags: translation

We are using CiviCRM in multi language mode (CiviCRM 4.6 on Drupal 7).

For public CiviCRM pages (like event registration), we are offering the CiviCRM language selector, which offers the users to change between "German" and "English (United States)".

Now, I would like to change "English (United States)" to simply "English".
How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just navigate to

Administer -> system settings -> option Groups

This will give you a list of all the Languages - so just edit and save the name which you wanted to.

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Thank you so much! So easy, but I did not get it by myself!